# Oracle: Run an Update Trigger Without Changing Data

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is there a way in Oracle to fire an update trigger without actually changing any data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE table SET column = column WHERE rownum = 1;` should fire the trigger [once] I think.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I also added WHERE rownum = 1 to limit the trigger to a single execution.

Comment: I'm updating the answer then because this is an important difference. Great!